# Enviar datos con un botón php a una tabla MySql sin formulario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, yii

Buen día¡

Espero me puedan ayudar.

tengo un boton en php que ejecuta un script.

lo que necesito es que cuando un usuario previamente logueado haga clic en ese boton se envie de manera automatica su nombre de usuario fecha y hora en la cual realizo la accion.

el boton es algo asi:

```
echo CHtml::button(Yii::t('site', 'Help (F2)'), array('id' => 'run_example'));
```

el js que se ejecuta es el siguiente:

```
<script> $("#run_example").click(function(){ Sideshow.start({ listAll:true });}); </script>
```

los datos que deseo enviar ya estan declarados en un controller:

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe;
public $language;
public $loginMobile;
private $_identity;

/**
 * Declares the validation rules.
 * The rules state that username and password are required,
 * and password needs to be authenticated.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // username and password are required
        array('username, password, language', 'required'),
        // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
        array('rememberMe, loginMobile', 'boolean'),
        // password needs to be authenticated
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
    );
}
```

Como veran estoy usando Yii framework
De antemano agradezco su ayuda

Buen día¡

Comment: Y a donde se tienen que enviar? o que es lo que no hace ahora? sé un poco más detallado con la duda

Comment: @FranIslas esa sintaxis  en el código es de yii, extensiones de yii2 no van a funcionar

Comment: @Sr1871 Ahhh perdón. Mala mía...

Comment: lo que no se como hacer es que al presionar el boton me envie los datos de usuario, hora y fecha a una tabla en MySql llamada Transaction_Log